# Willow PR2 svn repo

Tags: ros, svn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I clone this SVN repo: http://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/all.

I understand that this repo isn't used for development anymore, but I'd still like to clone it in order to navigate through revision history.

`$ svn co http://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/all
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/all'; please relocate
$ svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/all
Error validating server certificate for 'https://code.ros.org:443':

The certificate has expired.
Certificate information:
Hostname: *.ros.org
Valid: from Wed, 25 Apr 2012 00:00:00 GMT until Fri, 25 Apr 2014 23:59:59 GMT
Issuer: COMODO CA Limited, Salford, Greater Manchester, GB
Fingerprint: 4b:0b:52:6b:10:f4:d0:dc:42:03:22:f0:04:60:8f:df:e0:33:ff:c5
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? t
svn: URL 'https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/all' doesn't exist`

It is possible to use this interface to see the SVN repo: https://code.ros.org/gf/project/wg-ros-pkg/scmsvn, but I still want to checkout the SVN repo in order to have access to all the history on my machine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205705/willow-pr2-svn-repo/) by [gustavogoretkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11151/gustavogoretkin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2015-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that as of last week, this server is no longer accessible.

---

Originally posted by [gustavogoretkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11151/gustavogoretkin/) with karma: 28 on 2015-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0